# How to solve Unresponsive script error programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, browser

I am using kendo in my application and at sometime one of my pages is showing this error in IE and Firefox.But its working fine in Chrome.

```
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: resource://firebug/firebug-service.js:3442
```

I have searched and found that setting the value `dom.max_script_run_time` of this will solve the problem.My question is that is it possible to set the value programatically.I mean by using javascript or jquery.If so how.? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe off-topic, but did you read about web workers?

Comment: The best solution would be to find the bottleneck in your code and eliminate it.